# uibutton dosnt respond to touch when at a location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Bit of a strange one.

I have a UIButton which works when located anywhere on the view except the top left hand corner when in landscape mode.

I have a navigation bar with a back button nested in the same area but when the the video enters full screen and playback state changes this navigation bar is hidden.

any ideas?

Comment: For your UIButton not responding, add this code in viewDidLoad [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];

Comment: the uibutton does respond. its just when its located at CGRectmake (5,5,320,44) for e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thought, the problem was occuring due to the hidden navigation bar and the navigation item located in the same place.

The only solution i can find was to remove the navigation bar from superview then add it back when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your view's hierarchy is not properly configured. To properly configure your hierarchy, you need to navigate to either the xib or storyboard that you're working with, and re-order the button so that it's on top of anything that falls within it's similar bounds. A common example is that you added a `UIView`, which is clear, and you had the button underneath it, and now you can't interact with it even though you can't see it.